# Python list is not adding a singular word to the list

Tags: python, list

[(you can view the source here)](https://replit.com/@krab-cake/WordAI#main.py)

So I am running in to a issue.
Lets say I have a list named `mylist`.
When I add a word to the list, for example `cat`, it's not `['cat']` but instead `['c', 'a', 't']`. And my code has a function where it wants to eliminate combinations its already tried, so you can see how this is a problem. Any help?

here is the code:

```
import os
from random import randrange
from colorama import *

def clear():
  os.system('clear')

realWords = []
fakeWords = []

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']

words = []

sentence = ""

def testAWord():
    global fakeWords
    global realWords
    word = ""
    for i in range(randrange(10)):
        word += letters[randrange(len(letters))]
    
    for i in fakeWords:
        if word == i:
            print(Fore.RED + "Already in database: FAKE")
            break
    for i in realWords:
        if word == i:
            print(Fore.LIGHTBLUE_EX + "Already in database: REAL")
            break

    print(Fore.GREEN + "Lets test a word. Is "+ Fore.LIGHTGREEN_EX + word + Fore.GREEN +" a word?")
    isItAWord = input()
    
    if isItAWord == "y":
        realWords += str(word)
    elif isItAWord == "n":
        fakeWords += str(word)

    # if isItAWord == "m":
    #     sent = makeASentence()
    #     print(sent)
    if isItAWord == "v":
          print(Fore.GREEN + str(realWords))
          print(Fore.RED + str(fakeWords))
          input()
    clear()
  

    
while(True):
  testAWord()
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], there's much too much code here that is irrelevant to the problem you describe.

Comment: `When I add a word to the list` is not clear. Your [mre] should make it abundantly clear exactly when and where the issue is happening.

Comment: I'm guessing you need to `''.join()` your letters together at some point, but it's not clear where you need to do it

Comment: use `mylist.append('cat')` instead `+=`

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.append()` function:

```
if isItAWord == "y":
    realWords.append(str(word))
elif isItAWord == "n":
    fakeWords.append(str(word))
```

This will add the full word into your list, as opposed to the individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

`realWords += str(word)` is equivalent to `realWords.extend(str(word))`, which appends all elements from the iterable `str(word)` to the list one by one.

Example:

```
>>> realWords = []
>>> word = 'foo'
>>> realWords += str(word)
>>> realWords
['f', 'o', 'o']
```

What you want is `realWords.append(str(word))`. Same goes for the handling of `fakeWords`.

You can also omit `str` in `str(word)` if `word` is already a string (I didn't check).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add elements to an array by simply "+="ing your element to the array, instead you need to `[array].append([element])`.

.append(), appends the element to the end of the array.

So try changing:

```
if isItAWord == "y":
    realWords += str(word)
elif isItAWord == "n":
    fakeWords += str(word)
```

to:

```
if isItAWord == "y":
    realWords.append(str(word))
elif isItAWord == "n":
    fakeWords.append(str(word))
```

Comment: Your answer is 100% accurate, but just add a single **`** symbol  at both start and end of [array].append(str(word)).

Comment: @FaraazKurawle Why is that? (just curious)

Comment: that's not related to your answer, it's realted to the formatting of your answer, you can check yourself the diffrence too

Comment: Oh yeah, I see it now, thanks!